# Magento 2: Error on configurable products frontend: Element 'reference': This element is not expected

Tags: magento2, configurable-product, frontend-error

[image]

I am getting this error on the frontend on all configurable product detail pages. I have tried disabling all the modules and theme but the error still shows. Please help?

Answer (score 1):

The error refers to an invalid element `<reference/>` somewhere in your theme or module layout xml.

To search for all occurrences of `<reference`  run

```
grep -irl '<reference ' *
```

In your magento app and design folders.

Comment: I have disabled the theme and all of the extensions. It is still occurring.

Comment: Try searching your app and design folders - have updated my answer. What version of Magento 2 are you using? Do you have any layout data set via admin?

Comment: Okay. It is 2.3.4. No I dont have any layout data in admin.

Comment: search your DB table catalog_product_entity_text for value like "<reference %"

Comment: Thanks it worked. I removed the value containing '<reference' tag from 'catalog_product_entity_text' table for the particular product and it worked. But I can not find from where the value was added in the admin or code. Can you help me with that?